# Shutdown Quartz scheduler after current jobs complete

Tags: java, c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I am using Quartz for job scheduling in a Windows service. I need to shutdown the scheduler when the service is stopped or when the user changes the frequency of the job runs. As I would like to wait for the executing jobs, I use

```
scheduler.Shutdown(true);
```

I get in both cases the exception:

> Quartz.UnableToInterruptJobException: Job 'myJob' can not be
>   interrupted, since it does not implement Quartz.IInterruptableJob

The running service cannot be stopped which is quite bad.

But job interruption means not waiting for the job to complete? So, not what I want? Although it would solve the current exception problems.

What would be the correct implementation not causing `shutdown` to crash?

And if I really need to implement IInterruptableJob, how is this done? I don't find a tutorial about that and I don't really want to do anything different than a standard shutdown. I am using the standard scheduler factory for the scheduler creation:

```
schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to interrupt the job... I simply had to implement the `IInteruptableJob` interface, with an `interrupt` method doing nothing. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32574101/2320456) post helped me a lot!